# Javascript - leaflet map loads on localhost, error on server

Tags: javascript, html, apache, leaflet

I made a leaflet map in a div inside a webpage, when I load it on localhost it works fine, but when I upload it on a server it loads but not properly, disordered tiles and over the divs, any idea what could be the problem?, I uploaded similar maps on other webpages with the same base layer with no errors

I'm using apache2 and ubuntu server

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript or network errors in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: It says that files "style.css.map" and "bootstrap.css.map" are not found

Comment: The files are all in the same local, I watched the console while reloading and it says "Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://xxxxx/js/Leaflet.js” , ??

Comment: Find out why the file is not loading :D just a guess... did you name your file with a capital L on the server?

Comment: woops, that was it, so simple, thank you!!, btw, why it doesn't throw an error when loaded in localhost??

Comment: The windows file system is not case sensitive, but many other file systems are.

Answer (score -1):

Leaflet library takes a while to load on your host. Wait about 10 minutes and refresh again.